# Xamarin Enum.TryParse throw exception

Tags: xamarin

I am using Enum.TryParse in my converter. And sometimes there could be not enum in input value. On .net EnumTryParse simply return null in such cases. But on xamarin (at least on iOs) it throws FormatException. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Catch the `FormatException`? Check if the input value is null?

Comment: @Krumelur that could be done, but its really inconvenient when debugging exceptions.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue in Xamarin.iOS when using TryParse. When I look at the stack trace in my crash report, it's showing Parse and not TryParse. Wonder if TryParse doesn't translate well.